# Why does $P(X_i = X_j)= 0$ in this statement?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, random-variables

I've found this statement:

> $X_1\, \ldots X_k$ are independent random variables defined on the probability space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathfrak{B}, p)$, each with the same density $f$. Thus $(X_1\, \ldots X_k)$ is a random vector on $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}^n), P)$, i.e. the product of the $(\mathbb{R}, \mathfrak{B}, p)$.
>
> If $i \neq j$ then $$P(X_i = X_j)= \iint_{x_i = x_j}f(x_i)f(x_j) dx_i dx_j = 0$$

Why is the integral $0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the line $x_i=x_j$ has Lebesgue measure zero in the $(x_i,x_j)$-plane hence the integral of every function on it is zero.